# How to prove the existence of an infimum on a bounded set

Tags: general-topology

Definition of distance that I'm using:

In a metric space (X, d) (not necessarily Euclidean), define the ”distance” $d^1$ between a point $x ∈ X$ and a nonempty set $B ⊂ X$ as:

$d^1(x, B) ≡ inf_{b∈B} d(x, b)$.

$B$ means bounded set.

The statment I have to proof is:

$d^1$ is well-defined, that is, the infimum exists and is non-negative.

What I've already done:

Taken the set is bounded, we have that $∃ε$  s.t.  $B⊆N_{ε,X}  (x_i )$, hence: (I'm stuck here)

Edit: Solved some confusing issues.

Comment: Just use the fact that every nonempty set of real numbers which is bounded from below has an infimum.

Comment: and if it's bounded below by $0$, then the infimum is not smaller than $0$.

Comment: Very confusingly-written question. First you write, "definition of infimum I am using", but then you don't define infimum, but rather you define the number $d^1.$ Also the question doesn't mention boundedness, so I'm not sure why you're bringing that into the picture...

Comment: Edited for solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-empty set $\{d(x,b)\mid b \in B\}$ of reals is bounded below by $0$ (as metrics assume values $\ge 0$ always).

So the infimum of that set, your value $d^1(x,B)$ must exist, by standard properties of $\Bbb R$. Also, $0$ is *a* lower bound for that set and the infimum is the *largest* lower bound so $0 \le d^1(x,B)$ follows.

That's all.